# Using vfs_link in linux kernel mode

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am new to kernel programming. I want to rename a file in linux kernel mode. I did not find any direct functions which can do this. So I found that I can use `vfs_link` to create new hardlink and `vfs_unlink` to delete old link. But I did not understand how to use `vfs_link(struct dentry *old_dentry, struct inode *dir, struct dentry *new_dentry, struct inode **delegated_inode)`.

Say I have `struct file* fp` before using `vfs_link`.

I understand `old_dentry` is `fp->f_dentry`. But I am not decipher what other params are.
I did not find any concrete examples on net where `vfs_link` is used. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **don't want** to do that.

Kernel people always say that "policy does not belong to kernel". The kernel should do as userland tells it, but should never decide what to do and should never do complex things that the userland can easily compose of more basic operations. This sounds awful lot like policy.

The only part of kernel that works with inodes and dentries are implementations of the respective system calls and very special modules like ecryptfs and kernel nfsd. For anything that is not directly filesystem-related, you should not assume filesystem even exists!

Unless you are doing anything filesystem-related that really can't be done elsewhere, you should have userland tool manipulate files and feed the data in/read from kernel via device nodes or `/proc` or `/sys` special files (they are really just like devices, except identified by name rather than device numbers).

Now if you are really doing something filesystem related, you can easily look up the uses of [`vfs_link` on elixir.bootlin.com](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/A/ident/vfs_link). There are four uses in total. They are most likely **the only three uses in the whole universe**.

That is however **not the correct way to do rename**. There **is** a similar function [`vfs_rename`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/A/ident/vfs_rename). The semantics is different, because rename replaces target while link does not and also because it is allowed to rename directories but not to link them. `vfs_rename` has whopping **six** uses **in the whole universe**.

As for the arguments, if you *don't* have a `struct file*`. That would be a handle to *open* file, but you are linking one *path* to another *path*. `old_dentry` is the old filename, `new_dentry` is the new filename, `new_dir`/`dir` is the directory into which `new_dentry` should be placed, `old_dir` is the inode in which `old_dentry` lived (. I don't really know what `delegated_inode` is, but it has something to do with the nfsd (which is one of those three users of this function).

Comment: Say I have 2 files f1 and f2 in same directory d. I delete f2 and create a hard link of name f2 to f1. how would these map to the parameters(old_dentry, dir new_dentry, delegated_inode).

Comment: The links are dead.